# Linux: which standard directory has write access by default?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, deployment, jpackage

my application is required update its program files when it detects a new version on the server. The update mechanism is performed by the application itself, and it replaces old code with new code in the same directory. Which directory in linux is best suited for this? If there is a standard directory which has write access by default(analogous to `%AppData%\Local` for windows), I would like to know which one it is.

I have tried using `/var/<my-app-name-here>` and `/opt/<my-app-name-here>`, but none of these directories have write access by default. The only way I can use them update files in them is if the user uses sudo, so i would just like to avoid making those problems by just installing to a directory with write access to begin with.

I am using a tool called jpackage to make the .deb file which install the application.

Comment: users in linux have write access to their own home directory.

Comment: @stark I just checked, my program doesn't have write access to directories created on the home directory. Either I have to manually set up the permissions or run it under sudo(which is a bit of a pain to setup)

Comment: Then you are creating the directories with the wrong permission.  Show your code and someone can answer it instead of guessing.

Comment: There is no such thing (if you're talking about system global, which I assume since you're talking about a `deb`). But I think you're also abusing `%AppData%\Local` in Windows if your code lives there, it's meant for settings and configuration data, not self-updating executables files, plus it would install per user, not system-wide. If you insist on something as stupid as a globally accessible self-updating executable you could always make it SUID in e.g. `/opt`,  but I strongly recommend against it.

Comment: @tink I wouldn't say "abuse". A very popular game called [Spiral Knights](https://www.spiralknights.com) implements it in the same way on windows. And yeah, I'm looking to do this per-user too

Comment: I still see that as abuse, and it's defiitely not what the DEB package manager's makers had in mind; did you stumble upon this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/818025/140149) on [sf]?